# CALL dbms.security.createUser('user','pass',false) does not work

Tags: c#, authentication, neo4j, .net-core, graph-databases

I'm using the Neo4j desktop client for a proof of concept. I'm having trouble figuring out how to obtain credentials to call out to the Neo4j server to query from managed code. I'm using the driver, and I'm unsure how to actually obtain/manage credentials with Neo4j. All the places I've looked say that I should be able to run the following command in the terminal of the Browser for Neo4j...but doesn't work.

```
CALL dbms.security.createUser('username', 'password', false)
```

I get the following response when try to run that line.

[image]

I'm currently using version 3.3.1 for Neo4j, and it's being run as enterprise edition. Can anyone explain what is wrong? Am I missing some step to configure/unlock this API call to add a user?

Comment: What is the role of the user who fulfills this query?

Comment: I'm using the default account when you signup which I assume is admin.

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of the Desktop version :

> Anybody & everybody can get a free-for-development use (single-user,
>   local desktop/ single machine) license via Neo4j Desktop.

It's a single user database, so obviously you are not allow to create.

Comment: I believe this is correct. You can grab the [tar/zipped enterprise version](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/) for testing this part out if you want.